# Cannot Upload Image or Cannot Display Image

Tags: image, drupal, upload

I am new in using Drupal.

First, I downloaded and installed a Drupal free template on my localhost. Everything works fine.

However, when I duplicated the site from localhost to sharedhost for testing, the image cannot be uploaded nor displayed in the test site when I am adding or editing contents. I went to check with the sharedhost provider. So far it concludes that "safe mode off", and no error notice nor message is shown in the report.

I just try to upload an image in a new content type and change an image in an existing content. The error log shows:

"[Mon Aug 19 04:44:09 2013] [error] [client 218.102.131.79] File does not exist: /home/jwbb26i2/public_html/favicon.ico"

I have no idea on how to set the correct path. May I ask could you help me know how to set it properly?

We have no idea about this problem. Can anyone help me know or solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing cache?

Correct me if i'm wrong your question is "Drupal free template" meaning "theme" or the whole Drupal instance?

Comment: I downloaded a theme with demo content.  I modified it and use my own content.  I have tried clear all cache, but the problem is still not fixed.